# Laravel 7 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

after creating `user` migration i created `users_contact_lists`, for this migration of my project i get this error:

> Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

**i read some issues in SO and i can't found what's problem.**

```
Schema::create('users_contact_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('mobile_number');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

[image]

and i can't fix that by this cods:

> ```
> 1)  $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
> 2)  $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
> 3)  $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->nullable();
> ```

Comment: Your `posts` table doesn't exists yet when the `users_contact_lists` migration is executed. What do you mean with `->references('id')->on('posts')`? Perhaps `->references('id')->on('users')`?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved:**

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
```